# Capture event.clientX original value

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onmousemove

```
var startT = Date.now();
var startX = event.clientX;
var startY = event.clientY;
var endT = startT;
console.log(startX+","+endX);
while (endT < startT + 100) {
    endT = Date.now();
}
var endX = event.clientX;
var endY = event.clientY;
var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((endX - startX), 2) + Math.pow((endY - startY), 2));
var velocity = distance/100;
console.log(endT - startT);
console.log(startX+","+endX);
```

from event listener

```
<script>window.onmousemove = showPara;</script>
```

I was trying to calculate the distance and velocity that mouse moved over a time interval, but the `event.clintX` or `Y` will keep changing while the event happens, so do `startX` and `startY`. So the distance and the velocity are both `0`.
Is there any method that can capture the start coordinate at a constant value?

Answer (score 0):

You can store initial values on the `mousedown` event. And then compare them on `moousemove` and on `mouseup`.

Comment: But there is no click request in the process, what I wanna achieve is like a real-time cursor speed monitoring function.